# Why are badges not awarded as soon as we do a good job?

Tags: support, badges

When ever we do a job for which we deserve a badge, why aren't we awarded one as soon as we do it. Is it a bug or something? Or is some algorithm not well developed? Just curious, that's all.

Comment: It's not a bug, some badges are awarded at specific times, and many require a bit of time to process.  Having said that, badges are secondary to the main reason to being on the site.

Comment: @cVplZ not for me - sharing knowledge is my first priority

Comment: True medals in real life also take time until they are awarded. Sometimes long years.

Comment: @Shadow Wizard true medals are diferent from the ones you get here. In real life it obviously takes time to evaluate what ever we did for the medal and cal us and give it to us. But on SE our accounts will already be on their server. And like in my comment bellow, its just a matter of algorithms.

Comment: @Shadow Wizard sorry its not medals' its badges.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Because there are more important things for the system to do immediately than award badges. Badges are awarded by tasks that are scheduled to run at periodic times.

The algorithms are fine; the only problem is some people's need for immediate gratification. Learn some patience - waiting a few hours for a badge won't make you ill. Badges are meaningless in the global picture - they won't feed the hungry, cure the ill, or make the world a more peaceful place. If you're finding yourself so concerned with them you can't wait a day, your priorities are in the wrong place.

Comment: Most badges are awarded substantially more often than once a day.

Comment: @justabrickinthewall: So? It doesn't change my answer. Waiting a day, half a day, 6 hours, 3 hours... You get the badge. What difference does it make how soon? It's still a matter of needing instant gratification for something that is totally meaningless. But as you're being pedantic, I've rephrased to "at periodic times" - the difference is as relevant as the scheduling times.

Comment: The way I see it, it's more about a legitimate support question being turned into an assault on OP's character, accompanied by incorrect information.

Comment: I'll concede "incorrect information" as far as scheduling, which I've corrected. I stand by "immediate gratification" for the reasons I've stated - as long as you get the badge, why does it matter when it happens except for the need for "I want it now"? What's the impact of waiting (up to a day)?

Comment: Its not about immediate gratification. I was curious to know, because medals like autobiographer could be programmed to awarded as soon as we upload our information. And same with other medals too.

Comment: @Ken White its also not about being patient. When ever I get medal my reputation increases. With that done wont I get more privilages on SE. That helps me use it even better. So is it not importent to get them soon.

Comment: @Switch it's not "medal" but rather a "badge" and no, badges never give any reputation or privileges. They're for display/show only.

Comment: @Ken White sorry about that. I made the changes. But still even if its for show it does make others feel that we have some knowledge (when dealing with badges rewarded to knowledge related stuf). I dont mean to showoff, but what if someone does not agree with what some one said, doubting his/her knowledge.

Comment: @Ken White I understood how badges work now, but,like is said in my comment above, it could have been programmed to do it immedeatly. Is their server slow or something like that.

Comment: @Switch, I would imagine that the server is processing far more important tasks, keeping the place securely running.

Comment: @Switch: No, their server is not slow. It simply has more important things to do than award badges that are meaningless. If you're writing answers that depend on people seeing you have a badge for something to know whether to believe them or not, you're not writing good enough answers. I have never once read an answer to a question and thought "Well, I don't know if this answer is right or not... Does this person have a badge?". If you need to depend on a badge to make your answers believable, you need to write better answers.