# Help, I am not able to delete a post

Tags: support, vote-to-delete

I want to delete my post with a bad reputation and I am getting warnings about being blocked. Here's a link to it [Why are badges not awarded as soon as we do a good job?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/242899/why-are-badges-not-awarded-as-soon-as-we-do-a-good-job/)

Comment: @rene: this is far more about warnings than it is about deletion.

Comment: @rene: and it lists *why* the user wants to delete in the question body. Always read the whole question!

Comment: I figure it's about both question deletion **and** concerns of being blocked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things to remember:

- Question bans only apply on a per-site basis. Your one post getting downvoted won't get you a ban and even if you did get one eventually it would only apply to Meta.SE not any other sites.
- While apparently the warning messages are displayed here at the same point as other sites the actual limits for getting a ban are much higher. That's so people don't have to fear being blocked if they post the odd unpopular feature request or similar.

So in general don't worry about it.

Answer (score 2):

You are not able to delete a question that has a positively scored answer - refer to [How does deleting work? What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean? What are the criteria for deletion?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that), particularly in the answers:

> When can't I delete my own post?
>
> You can't delete answers that have been accepted.
>
> You can't delete any question that:
>
> has an upvoted answer, or has multiple answers (even if there are no
>   upvotes) You can't delete any of your questions or answers if you
>   haven't registered your account (that is, associated an OpenID with
>   it).

Best to read and act on any information (if available) from the warnings.

If you feel strongly about it, flag your post and select 'Other' and write a message for moderator review - then it is up to them to decide what to do.

Deleting answers still count towards question bans, but one question won't necessarily invoke it.

Answer (score 2):

You won't be question banned for that. The question ban algorithm on Meta has been *severely tweaked* to prevent banning over a few negatively-received questions.

Meta is a place for discussion and support, and as such voting works differently.

The *warning system* on the other hand has not been adjusted (yet). You can safely ignore those here.

Note that even if you deleted your question, it would still count towards a question ban *anyway*, only now you can no longer improve it to try and attract upvotes!